# When I click on submit button, it navigates to bottom of web page automatically

Tags: html, css

I want to know that lets say I am on top of a web page in my application (Html, Javascript, php,css), how come when I click on a submit button in a form, that it then navigates to the bottom of the page?

Can this be fixed?

Below is an example of code I have:

```
<?php

if ($sessionMinus == $_SESSION['initial_count']){ 

    $action = 'thankyou.php'; 

}elseif($sessionMinus != $_SESSION['initial_count']){ 

    $action = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; 

}

?>

    <form id="QandA" action="<?php echo htmlentities($action); ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return myClickHandler()">

    .....//A html table

    <p><input id="submitBtn" name="submitDetails" type="submit" value="Submit Details" /></p>


    </form>
```

Comment: I think we need to see your code to have something to work with. But Anton's answer looks plausible.

Comment: how come it happens? MAGIC..please share your code...

Comment: what's the action of your form? `page.php#blahblah?`

Comment: ya see, your form action is causing problems

Comment: Is it cause it is php_self that it is doing this? if so is there a way to sort this out in like css or something like that?

Comment: you can do it only with JS or direct write it into html source

Answer (score 0):

it looks that forms action is link some like `<p><a href="#bottom">some text</a></p>`
in order to fix this you need check attribute on your form.

Comment: yes it may be, but what is action in your form? and does your form request? any errors in console?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have one header div with `divHeader` Id and a Footer div with `divFooter` Id. Then give your javascript code to button `onclick` Event. so that it will redirect to the footer whenever you clicks on it. Use `a` tags to achieve it ( a tags are easy to understand)